# Call to weight in lm() within function doesn't evaluate properly

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation

I'm writing a function that requires a weighted regression. I've repeatedly been getting an error with the weights parameter, and I've created a minimal reproducible example you can find here:

```
wt_reg <- function(form, data, wts) {
  lm(formula = as.formula(form), data = data,
     weights = wts)
}

wt_reg(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, wts = 1:nrow(mtcars))
```

This returns

> Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'wts' not found

If you run this all separately, it works fine. I've dug into lm, and it appears the issue is a call to `eval(mf, parent.frame())`. Even though wts is in the parent.frame(), it doesn't appear to be evaluated correctly within the call. Here's a little more detail:

mf is assigned such that it's the same as

```
stats::model.frame(formula = as.formula(form), data = data, weights = wts, 
    drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
```

When I run

```
parent.frame()$wts
```

it does return a numeric vector. But when I run

```
eval(stats::model.frame(formula = as.formula(form), data = data, weights = wts, 
    drop.unused.levels = TRUE), parent.frame())
```

it doesn't.

I can run

```
stats::model.frame(formula = as.formula(parent.frame()$form), 
    data = parent.frame()$data, weights = parent.frame()$wts, 
    drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
```

and it works. You can test this yourself if you want using the example from the top.

Any thoughts? I really have no idea what's going on here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Formulas are special in R in that they not only keep track of symbol/variable names, they also keep track of the environment where they were created. Check out

```
ff <- mpg ~ cyl
environment(ff)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
foo <- function() {
  ff <- mpg ~ cyl
  environment(ff)
}
foo()
# <environment: 0x0000026172e505d8> private function environment (different each time)
```

The problem is that `lm` will try to use the data.frame you pass in and the environment where the formula was created to look up variables rather than the parent frame. Since you create the formula in the call to `wt_reg`, the formula holds on the the global scope. But `wts` only exists in the function scope. You can alter your function to change the environment on the formula to the local function environment then everything should work

```
wt_reg <- function(form, data, wts) {
  ff <- as.formula(form)
  environment(ff) <- environment()
  lm(formula = ff, data = data,
     weights = wts)
}

wt_reg(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, wts = 1:nrow(mtcars))
```

The `eval(mf, parent.frame)` you are referring to in `lm()` is calling `model.frame()` with your formula. And from the description on the `?model.frame` help page: "All the variables in formula, subset and in ... are looked for first in data and then in the environment of formula (see the help for formula() for further details) and collected into a data frame". So it again is looking in the environment of the formula, not the calling frame.

Alternatively, you could move the weights into the data object you are passing to `lm` itself. This would work

```
wt_reg <- function(form, data, wts) {
  lm(form, data = cbind(data, wts=wts),
     weights = wts)
}

wt_reg(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, wts = 1:nrow(mtcars))
```

Comment: So then the call to `parent.frame()` in `eval(mf, parent.frame)` doesn't do what I think it's doing?

Comment: This still isn't working for me. See:

```
wt_reg <- function(form, data, wts) {
  form = as.formula(form)
  lm(formula = form, data = data,
     weights = wts)
}

wt_reg(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, wts = 1:nrow(mtcars))
```

Comment: I'll also note that it's able to find the `data` and `form` arguments just fine! If I do this kind of thing with no weight argument it works.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "still isn't working". Your code in the comment doesn't reassign the environment so it doesn't adrees the problem. `as.formula` will not change the environment for things that are already formulas. I added a bit about why `eval(mf, parent.frame())` doesn't do what you think it does. It works fine without the weights because all those objects are in the global environment.

Comment: Oh no, your version is working! I still don't understand why.

Comment: It struck me that I shouldn't need to explicitly call environment if I create the formula outside the function. Or that the data argument should break.

Comment: The thing that I just can't understand is why `ff <- as.formula(form , env = environment())` doesn't work.

Comment: Because `as.formula` is meant to coerce things that aren't already formulas. If you pass in something that is already a formula, it won't change it. That code would work if you passed in your formula as a string for example: `wt_reg("mpg ~ cyl", ...)`. Then the coercion to formula would use that environment.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I could have just looked at the source and figured that out. Thanks.