# How can I pass weights in a variable to rpart?

Tags: r, rpart

For some reason, the `rpart` from the `rpart` package can't see a variable defined in the context from which it is called. You can see in the reprex below that `wts` is defined just before the call to `rpart`, but when I call `rpart`, I get the error "`object 'wts' not found`".

If I omit the `weights` argument, there is no problem.

```r
library(rpart)

data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")

scale <- function(x) {
    x/sum(x)
}

fit_rpart <- function(formula, data, iters = 10) {
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
    models <- list()

    for (i in 1:iters) {
        wts <- scale(runif(nrow(data)))
        print(head(wts))
        models[[i]] <- rpart(formula = formula,
                             data = data, weights = wts,
                             method = "class")
    }
    return(models)
}

results <- fit_rpart(cyl == 4  ~ drv + cty + fl + class, mpg)
#> [1] 0.0072092177 0.0059019498 0.0007893446 0.0038617957 0.0067420603
#> [6] 0.0076892493
#> Error in eval(extras, data, env): object 'wts' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is *similar* to that provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164404/call-to-weight-in-lm-within-function-doesnt-eI%20puvaluate-properly). (Similar, but not the same, as this issue relates to `rpart`, not `lm`. Not sure how to generalize the question to cover both.)

If I put these two lines at the top of `fit_rpart`, the code runs fine.

```r
formula <- as.formula(formula)
environment(formula) <- environment()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a name scoping problem as you said. You can also use `<<-` to pass an affectation to the parent environment.

(Also, `data` and `formula` are already existing objects in R so to be clear one could prefer to rename them).

```r
library(rpart)

data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")

scale <- function(x) {
  x/sum(x)
}

fit_rpart <- function(f, d, iters = 10) {
  
  d <- as.data.frame(d)
  models <- list()

  for (i in 1:10) {
    wts <<- scale(runif(nrow(d)))
    print(head(wts))
    models[[i]] <- rpart(formula = f,
                         data = d,
                         weights = wts,
                         method = "class")
  }
  return(models)
}

results <- fit_rpart(cyl == 4  ~ drv + cty + fl + class, mpg)

# [1] 0.0007921094 0.0039999229 0.0026862458 0.0018832820 0.0006866826 0.0076998391
# [1] 0.005962060 0.006942240 0.001572535 0.009360314 0.005485438 0.008135806
# [1] 0.007224990 0.004209857 0.007706282 0.007071345 0.003784652 0.006335056
# [1] 0.004098536 0.003289626 0.006710783 0.007364727 0.003099702 0.007693150
# [1] 0.005154814 0.001212012 0.001169259 0.005829825 0.004401704 0.004269959
# [1] 0.001262500 0.003705485 0.007466314 0.005450551 0.001292365 0.007920012
# [1] 0.0007083308 0.0033698483 0.0073883706 0.0013445097 0.0068669108 0.0048488413
# [1] 0.005139870 0.002053938 0.002125759 0.006488419 0.007129400 0.006937384
# [1] 0.006957664 0.006296365 0.000640707 0.008121049 0.008014404 0.007706194
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you have identified the issue (see my answer, which I worked out after posting), but I still get an error when I `reprex::reprex` your code.

Comment: @IanGow, my bad, here is a quick fix based the mentionned SO answer.